# How do I get the username for an id from a list of ids

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I print my allusers list I get this :

```
allusers {
           2BrbqqlkVf1NSocm58qr95iL5h2: {…}, 
           7VQMBXdTPIZZZ8ztOLx9JEeRty1: {…}, 
           HNXrFSF3YoT07qapsz3xE9ODGp2: {…}, 
           NwiWN3xDq3awRghWscVBEmxaclB2: {…}, 
           P7P4Vc5hy1ZrYY9YDB5AfNIpQf2: {…},
 …}
```

each one of the ids look like this :

`2BrbbqqlkVf1NSocm58q95iL5h2: {Username: "ee", Email: "ee@gmail.com"}`

I have the id stored in candidateid , how do I get the user name?
I tried this:

```
<Button onClick={() => setchosen(candidateid)}>
  <h1>{allusers.candidateid.Username}</h1> 
</Button>
```

I also tried using .map and it doesn't work

Comment: `allusers[candidateid].Username`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use candidateId as a property-access because javascript will try to find a property on `allUsers` with the literal name candidateId.

What you want to do is:

```
allusers[candidateId].Username
```

That uses the value saved in `candidateId`.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do:

```
allusers[candidateId].Username
```